# VBA Excel error, while attempting to write a value from array in a cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a big VBA script, that starts an external program, waits, then reads the results into several arrays and writes some values in a table.
So I regularly get an error at the following place

```
Sheets("Calc").Cells(active_line_num, 1).Value = PiKa(i, j)
```

where *PiKa* is an array; 
*i*, *j* are feasible indices,

*active_line_num* has also a totally feasible value.
These lines are in the outer loop, and mostly it works w/o problems. But at some iterations it stops.

So the program breakes and suggests me to debug it. 
In debugging mode if I press F8 immidiately (next step) it reproduces the error.
But afteer some time (a minute or two) if I press F8 - everythig is running further w/o any errors.

The error is **Run-Time Error '9', Subscript out of range**

Here are two printscreens [imgur.com/a/MOPwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ2bD.jpg) 
One can see, that PiKa (9,6) as well as next 4 arrays exist and even have nonzero values. 
All these arrays are defined in the module as

```
Public PiKa() as Double
```

w/o dimentions and then are redimentioned once at the very beginnig of the program (not in the loops!)

```
ReDim PiKa(0 To nrc, 0 To 99)
```

What can it be?

Comment: Hve you tried to add a Watch on `PiKa(i,j)` and see the result? Have you tried to rewrite your code using jagged arrays?

Comment: `Run-Time Error '9', Subscript out of range` tells you what the problem is... either `active_line_num` is bigger than the number of lines the sheet has or `i`/`j` is not inside the limits of `pika`... please put directly in front of the error-line the code: `Debug.Print active_line_num & " - " & LBound(PiKa) & "/" & UBound(PiKa) & "(" & i & ") - " & LBound(PiKa, 2) & "/" & UBound(PiKa, 2) & "(" & j & ")"` now if the error pops up, check the last line of your output (this will slow down the process and should be deleted/commented out if the code runs fine)

Comment: GisMofx & Dirk, if you check my printscreens, you will see all those variables on the right. And even if they are not in those limits, why after couple of minutes the code could be executed further w/o any errors?